# Decorated arrow - New math symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows, decorations

I would like to add new arrows to the list of arrows below. This arrows will be used as math symbols.

[image]

The first problem I met is that the first arrow has a bigger head than to two others.

[image]

I would also like to add vertical lines like in the picture below.

[image]

The last thing I would like to achieve is to superimpose the two last arrows so as to build a last new one.

[image]

Here is the code giving the arrows of the screenshot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\rightarrow$

$\rightarrowtail$

$\twoheadrightarrow$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending on where and how you want to use your arrows, you might be interested in the arows from tikz: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (0,0)-- (1,0);
\draw [>->] (0,-0.5)-- (1,-0.5);
\draw [->>] (0,-1)-- (1,-1);
\draw [>->>] (0,-1.5)-- (1,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`

Comment: I would like to have new math symbols.

Comment: I have look for the symbols but I only find three black arrows without any decoration. I would like more symbols : this is to talk about partial or total applications that are injective, surjective or one-to-one. I met this formalism when reading a book about B language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution with the `old-arrow` package and the `\stackinset` command from `stackengine`:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{stackengine, graphicx} %
    \usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, old-arrows}%, relsize}
    \newcommand\vrightarrow{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{-0.1ex}{c}{0.15ex}{\scalebox{1}[0.4]{$ \vert $}}{ ―――→ }}}
    \newcommand\vrightarrowtail{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{-0.02ex}{\scalebox{1}[0.3]{$ \vert $}}{\rightarrowtail}}}
    \newcommand\vtwoheadrightarrow{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{-0.22ex}{c}{-0.02ex}{\scalebox{1}[0.3]{$ \vert $}}{\twoheadrightarrow}}}
    \newcommand\vtwoheadrightarrowtail{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{-0.12ex}{c}{-0.02ex}{\scalebox{1}[0.3]{$ \vert $}}{\mathrlap{\rightarrowtail}\mkern0.3mu\twoheadrightarrow}}}

    \begin{document}

    $\begin{matrix}
    A \vrightarrow B & A \vrightarrowtail B \\
    A \vtwoheadrightarrow B & A \vtwoheadrightarrowtail B
    \end{matrix}$

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting to see how to mix symbols by hand. :-)

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest you use a font that contains all the desired arrows such as the [STIX fonts](https://ctan.org/pkg/stix2-otf/). Those are best to be used with XeLaTeX and installation of the fonts to the operating system of your computer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
    \toprule
    Glyph & Unicode & LaTeX \\
    \midrule
    $\char"2192$ & 2192 & \verb+$\char"2192$+ \\
    $\char"21A0$ & 21A0 & \verb+$\char"21A0$+ \\
    $\char"21A3$ & 21A3 & \verb+$\char"21A3$+ \\
    $\char"2916$ & 2916 & \verb+$\char"2916$+ \\
    \midrule
    $\char"21F8$ & 21F8 & \verb+$\char"21F8$+ \\
    $\char"2900$ & 2900 & \verb+$\char"2900$+ \\
    $\char"2914$ & 2914 & \verb+$\char"2914$+ \\
    $\char"2917$ & 2917 & \verb+$\char"2917$+ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With PDFLaTeX, you can use the (deprecated) package `stix` with `\usepackage{stix}`. The arrows have the following (self explanatory) macros:

- `\rightarrow`
- `\twoheadrightarrow`
- `\rightarrowtail`
- `\twoheadrightarrowtail`
- `\nvrightarrow`
- `\nvtwoheadrightarrow`
- `\nvrightarrowtail`
- `\nvtwoheadrightarrowtail`

Comment: Thanks for the XeLaTeX solution but I prefer the "old school" design.

Comment: My sincere compliments for the work and the explanation.

Comment: Such a nice suggestion....